# Suggestions for first-time sourceforge project contributer?

Tags: python, open-source, licensing, sourceforge

Hey all.  I'm a professional software developer here in Seattle, WA USA.  I program for/work in a Windows shop, but I've recently began considering contributing to an Open Source project, specifically one under the Python License (CNRI Python License).

I realize that contacting a human resources representative where I work is the first step, but could any existing source forge contributors give me any advice?

Comment: Why HR "first"?  Start by asking your manager!

Comment: I'm guessing HR has the employment contract on file. Clarification of programming ownership / "conflict of interests" may be worthwhile. Some contracts contain boiler plate intellectual property ownership claims for any and all work done by the employee for the duration of employment. Any open source contributions to a project related his employer's market segment that is seen as undercutting Sean's employer could be seen as a conflict of interest. (I'm assuming the employer sells software or IT services).

Comment: HR is the last place I'd ask... start with your manager. If you're valued by your manager and your time spent on OSS doesn't negatively impact your day job, your manager will be much more likely to stand up for you should HR or legal raise an objection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is that there'll be no problem with it.  :)  Thanks for all the help, you guys!